# How to properly navigate through a 2d array?

Tags: java

So im trying to navigate a toy through a 2d array to get from one corner of the 2d array to the other side of the 2d array. The array is 8x8 and the toy can only turn right and downwards. The grid would look something like this.

0,12,7,43,32,12,30,15

21,26,18,34,41,9,17,21

20,43,23,35,23,20,17,37

5,29,28,18,9,42,35,24,

25,15,36,25,21,9,14,19,

25,26,32,,18,17,19,25,15

35,15,12,21,24,26,14,35,

15,12,18,25,14,22,21,15

Now to get from (0,0) to (8,8). It has to look at the number(which is just the number of seconds in the case of the question) to the right and down and see which one is smaller. Whichever one is smaller it will go that way. Now the question is to find the shortest time to reach (8,8) and it will output the direction it went and the total value at the end.

Sample Output (for the grid provided above):

```
total= 234

direction= RRDDDRRDRRDDDR
```

I have done most of the code properly, just my total value and directions doesn't match with the sample output. I feel it is a logic error and can't seem to find it. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code so far.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;


public class toygrid {
  static int[][] gridarray = new int[8][8];
  static int f=0;
  static int sum=0;
  static String direction="";
  
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        int [][]gridarray = {{ 0,21,20, 5,25,25,35,15},{12,26,43,29,15,26,15,12},
                             { 7,18,23,28,36,32,12,18},{43,34,35,18,25,18,21,25},
                             {32,41,23, 9,21,17,24,14},{12, 9,20,42, 9,19,26,22},
                             {30,17,17,35,14,25,14,21},{15,21,37,24,19,15,35,15}};
        
        grid(gridarray);

       // System.out.println(grid(gridarray));
    }
  
  static void grid(int[][] gridarray)
  {
   for(int i=0; i<7;i++)
   {
     
     for(int j=0; j<7;j++)
     {
       if(i*j==49)
       {
         break;
       }
       else
       {
         if(gridarray[i][j+1] < gridarray[i+1][j])
         {
           direction +="R";
           sum +=gridarray[i][j+1];
           j=j+1;
         }else
         {
           direction +="D";
           sum +=gridarray[i+1][j];
           i=i+1;
         }
       }
         
     }
     
   }
   System.out.println(direction + " SUM:" +sum );
  // System.out.println(gridarray.length);
    
  }



}
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the process with a debugger?

Comment: @wobr No, how do I do that?

Comment: I don't understand your logic at all.  You seem to want to iterate over every row and column with the two outer loops.  How is that a walk through the grid?  But then you also add to `i` or `j` with each iteration even though you're also incrementing those values in your `for` loops.  Are you supposed to just take the one route through based on always picking the shortest next time, or are you supposed to find the shortest path possible, even if you sometimes pick the larger number?  I don't see you trying multiple paths and comparing their total times.

Comment: @Steve Yeah the code is suppose to compare each right and down value every time it moves to find the quickest time to get to the end. But yeah its not suppose to pick the bigger number thats the problem

Comment: But picking the smallest number every time doesn't guarantee you the shortest total path through.

Comment: @Steve heres a bit from what the question im working on asks  "The method will take as a parameter an 8 x 8 grid of numbers starting with the top left corner (0,0) and ending with the bottom right(7,7). These numbers are the number of seconds that it takes for the tank to move onto that particular square (oddly enough it takes the same time regardless of the direction it comes from.) Your output will be the fastest time the tank can make it to the last square as well as proper directions. You may assume that it will always take less than 1000 seconds total."

Comment: indeed a bit confused, first of all you can calculate the best route with an algo, and i would guess thats the exercise all about, secondly to solve these types of problems, a more real-functional language would be used like Haskell or even Lisp, if you really want to iterate.....

Comment: it can be easily done with recursion, since `bestPath(i,j) = min(bestPath(i, j+1), bestPath(i+1, j)`, and base case is `bestPath(8,8) = grid[8][8]`. I can do it tomorrow if you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description:

> It has to look at the number(which is just the number of seconds in
> the case of the question) to the right and down and see which one is
> smaller. Whichever one is smaller it will go that way.

you don't need `for` loops at all.  Just keep an `x` and `y` value to track your current position, then decide whether you should go right or down. You'll also need to track whether you're at the right or bottom edge, in which case you wouldn't make a decision, you'd just move along the appropriate edge until you hit the corner.

So we can use a `do...while` loop until we hit that bottom corner:

```
  public static void navigateGrid(int[][] gridarray)
  {
    int yUpperBound = gridarray.length;
    int xUpperBound = gridarray[0].length; // assume all rows have same width

    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int sum = 0;
    boolean goRight;
    String direction = "";
    do {
      if (x < (xUpperBound-1) && y < (yUpperBound-1)) {
        // we can go right OR down, so we have to make a decision
        goRight = (gridarray[y][x+1] < gridarray[y+1][x]);
      }
      else {
        // we can either go right, or we can't; then we have to go down
        goRight = (x < (xUpperBound-1)); 
      }
      if (goRight) {
        x++;
        direction = direction + "R";
      }
      else {
        y++;
        direction = direction + "D";
      }
      sum = sum + gridarray[y][x];
    } while (x!=(xUpperBound-1) || y!=(yUpperBound-1));
    System.out.println(direction + " SUM:" + sum);   
  }
```

Here's the data from your matrix in your CODE (not the description), placed into Excel with the path highlighted that you would take based on your description:

[image]

For reference, here's your declaration for the array:

```
int [][]gridarray = {{ 0,21,20, 5,25,25,35,15},{12,26,43,29,15,26,15,12},
                         { 7,18,23,28,36,32,12,18},{43,34,35,18,25,18,21,25},
                         {32,41,23, 9,21,17,24,14},{12, 9,20,42, 9,19,26,22},
                         {30,17,17,35,14,25,14,21},{15,21,37,24,19,15,35,15}};
```

Comment: where is the static void main method, it says its missing and gives error

Comment: ?...just add one in like you have in your code.  Then call `navigateGrid(gridarray);`.  You can add a static main() to any class...

Comment: By the way, the description (and the approach I've given) is an example of a [Greedy Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm).  It is easy to implement, but is definitely not likely to the "best" solution.

Comment: Also this gives an output of RRDDDRRDRRRDDD SUM:243 instead of SUM:234 RRDDDRRDRRDDDR

Comment: Pretty sure your example and code DO NOT MATCH...so you might want to look real close at all of your numbers.  Look closely at the array in your description, vs. the array in your code.  Not the same.

Comment: Kinda weird because I noticed that and changed the array but still same results hmm

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Best path is 234 weight, [D, D, R, R, R, D, D, R, D, D, R, R, R, D]. Each steps was the values : [0, 12, 7, 18, 23, 28, 18, 9, 21, 9, 14, 25, 14, 21, 15]

As pointed in comments, you can't just "go to the minimum just down or right", if you want the best TOTAL path. (Example, maybe I have 1 down, and 2 right, but if i go down, I'll get a lot of big values after that I would maybe not have if I picked 2 right)

Recursion can be easier for those kind of problem. The most complicated was to store the steps

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class LabiLab {
    static int f = 0;
    static int sum = 0;
    static String direction = "";
    static int[][] gridarray = {
            {0, 21, 20, 5, 25, 25, 35, 15},
            {12, 26, 43, 29, 15, 26, 15, 12},
            {7, 18, 23, 28, 36, 32, 12, 18},
            {43, 34, 35, 18, 25, 18, 21, 25},
            {32, 41, 23, 9, 21, 17, 24, 14},
            {12, 9, 20, 42, 9, 19, 26, 22},
            {30, 17, 17, 35, 14, 25, 14, 21},
            {15, 21, 37, 24, 19, 15, 35, 15}};

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LabiPath bestLabiPath = bestPath(0, 0);
        System.out.println(bestLabiPath.steps);
        System.out.println(bestLabiPath.distance);
        System.out.println(bestLabiPath.distancePerStep);
    }

    static LabiPath bestPath(int i, int j){
        if (i==7 && j==7) return new LabiPath(gridarray[i][j], Arrays.asList("X"), Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(gridarray[i][j])));
        else if (i == 7) {
            LabiPath labiPathToRight = bestPath(i, j + 1).copyWithStepAndDistance("R", gridarray[i][j]);
            return labiPathToRight;
        }
        else if (j == 7) {
            LabiPath labiPathToDown = bestPath(i + 1, j).copyWithStepAndDistance("D", gridarray[i][j]);
            return labiPathToDown;
        }
        else {
            LabiPath labiPathToRight = bestPath(i, j + 1).copyWithStepAndDistance("R", gridarray[i][j]);
            LabiPath labiPathToDown = bestPath(i + 1, j).copyWithStepAndDistance("D", gridarray[i][j]);
            return labiPathToDown.compareTo(labiPathToRight) < 0 ? labiPathToDown : labiPathToRight;
        }
    }
}

class LabiPath implements Comparable {
    int distance;
    List<String> steps ;
    List<String> distancePerStep ;


    public LabiPath(int distance, List<String> steps, List<String> distancePerStep) {
        this.distance = distance;
        this.steps = steps;
        this.distancePerStep = distancePerStep;
    }

    public LabiPath copyWithStepAndDistance(String step, int distanceForStep){
        int newDistance = this.distance + distanceForStep;
        ArrayList<String> stepsCopy = new ArrayList<>(this.steps);
        List<String> distancePerStepCopy = new ArrayList<>(this.distanceForStep);
        LabiPath newLabiPath = new LabiPath(newDistance, stepsCopy,  distancePerStepCopy);
        newLabiPath.steps.add(0, step);
        newLabiPath.distancePerStep.add(0, String.valueOf(distanceForStep));
        return newLabiPath;
    }


    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof LabiPath) {
            return distance - ((LabiPath) o).distance;
        }
        else throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: This cannot appear in an allocation expression! in line 56.

Comment: Path newPath = new Path(this.distance+distance, new ArrayList<>(steps), new ArrayList<>(this.distancePerStep));

Comment: What's your Java version

Comment: Ok, strange because this line hasn't nothing new. However I used List.of which comes from Java ~9. I edited, can you retry it ?

Comment: 1 error found:
File: C:\Users\Assignment\LabiLab.dj  [line: 58]
Error: This cannot appear in an allocation expression!

Comment: Well, can't help you for that. Strange error, never had it with Java